# How to set an assembly as "fully trusted" in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an assembly which I need to load without invoking the strong name validation (since it's delay signed). Is there a way to make it fully-trusted in .NET 4?

The mscorcfg.msc utility has been removed from the .NET SDK, so it's impossible to use the old method (described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eccaxwce(v=vs.90).aspx) for example).

Comment: The point of delay-signing is to *still* be able to survive a strong name validation.  It only works on the machine where the delay signing was done.  Hard to believe this is a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4, by invoking it via a managed .EXE it is automatically fully trusted. Otherwise it is done by configuring the .NET host (such as IIS).